# Vb.Net - 'The given key was not present in the dictionary' on DATE_FORMAT using MySQL Stored Procedure

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I'm using a MySQL stored procedure with parameters and calling it from vb.net winforms app.

Here's how I call it in VB:

```
    Try
        sqlConn.Open()

        Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand("SP_DAILY", sqlConn)
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@serial", txtSerial.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@datefrom", dtpFrom.Value)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dateto", dtpTo.Value)

        Dim rdr As MySqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader
        If rdr.HasRows Then
            While rdr.Read
                Console.WriteLine(rdr(0) & " - " & rdr(1) & " - " & rdr(2))
            End While
        Else
            Console.WriteLine("Serial not found")
        End If

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    Finally
        sqlConn.Close()
    End Try
```

Here's the stored proc:

```
    SELECT 
        Name, 
        SerialNo, 
        DATE_FORMAT(datetime, '%Y/%m/%d') AS Date
    FROM table t 
    WHERE date(dateTime) BETWEEN datefrom AND dateto 
        AND SerialNo = serial
```

I've tried removing the Date_format and it works just well, but I want to format the date as the format above.

I've also tried using DATE(datetime) but I'm not getting the right format.

PS. The stored proc works fine when calling it in MySQL itself using CALL SP_DAILY (parameters), but getting the error when calling it from VB. I wonder why the error occurs when using DATE_FORMAT function and calling it from VB.

Comment: Why not just retrieve the actual data in the sproc and then format that `Date` value in your VB code?  That way, at the very least, you can use the same sproc again if you want to display the date in some other format elsewhere.

Comment: To be clear, are you saying that the sproc is called successfully using that code without `DATE_FORMAT` but not with, while it works either way using MySQL Workbench or the like?

Comment: I store the whole result in a datatable so I'm not sure If I can format it that way. Yes I can call the SP without DATE_FORMAT but not with.

Comment: Of course you can format it that way.  You can format it anyway you want, e.g. `Console.WriteLine($"{rdr(0)} - {rdr(1)} - {rdr(2):yyyy-dd-MM}")`.  You just provide the appropriate format specifier in the appropriate place.

Comment: pass parameter with specifying parameter datatype

Comment: Not sure if MySQL is fussy about case but you have datetime as a field name in the Select and dateTime in the Where clause.